# gsoap generated wsdl not working with eclipse WebServices explorer

Tags: c, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, gsoap

I have a gsoap-generated webservice server. Gsoap generated a WSDL file which describes the webservice. I wanted to use Eclipse's Web Services Explorer to test the webservice.

The first stage of wsdl loading passes, though an error is displayed:

```
IWAB0380E Errors were encountered while validating XML schemas.
XSD: The location '' has not been resolved because the import is unused
IWAB0381I file:\\\filepath.wsdl was successfully opened.
```

I can see a list of methods defined in the webservice, however when I click on one of them, there is no option to fill or send the request at all.

I don't have any more information from eclipse's tool. I have not idea what part of wsdl is wrong. If there is a part of the wsdl that would help find the problem, let me know which. The whole wsdl is available here: http://pastebin.com/GC1TgbTy

I do not have a good knowledge of wsdl and soap. I would guess that the error is somewhere in the definitions and namespaces, but I don't know where. Here is the start of the wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="isis_ws"
 targetNamespace="urn:isis"
 xmlns:tns="urn:isis"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:isis="urn:isis"
 xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
 xmlns:MIME="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
 xmlns:DIME="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/dime/wsdl/"
 xmlns:WSDL="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"

 xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<types>

 <schema targetNamespace="urn:isis"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:isis="urn:isis"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  elementFormDefault="unqualified"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an answer to the problem, but a workaround.

A free application called SoapUI ([download link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/)) is working fine with a gsoap-generated wsdl.